# Regarding embedding a application with WPF webpage

Tags: c#, wpf, web, wpf-controls, html

I created a application let say "Mydesktopapp"(which is mix of C# and c++ deliverables and few XML's file). 
'Mydesktopapp' can be run by clicking a batch file. Hence once user click on batch file, application gets executed and does it functionality on a desktop system.
*Now i want to provide this application to the user through a webpage*(so that everybody don't need to explicitly copy Mydesktopapp and then run it, instead user should just open a webpage from anywhere...and should click a button on webpage and application should get downloaded and run.
To achieve this...i created a webpage with a button and published it. On button click i will run the batch file. but i don't know how to embed Mydesktopapp with webpage...so that it get published with it and get downloaded automatically when user open webpage.

I am new to WPF but yes..i don't want to create a WCF(or webservice etc ) instead i just want to enbed/attach this app with my webpage and get it downloaded automatically.

Please provide help.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8976060/1136211) might be heplful.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is Silverlight or WPF browser application, since wpf is primarily a desktop application, I 'll recommend you to opt for silverlight for the web based solutions

**From Microsoft's website**

Silverlight is a powerful development tool for creating engaging, interactive user experiences for Web and mobile applications. Silverlight is a free plug-in, powered by the .NET framework and compatible with multiple browsers, devices and operating systems, bringing a new level of interactivity wherever the Web works.

more info on Silverlight at http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/

Comment: Yes...I created webpage using WPF browser application. But my problem is how to provide 'mydesktopapp' with this webpage to the user so that it gets downloaded automatically once user open the webpage.

Comment: due to security reasons you can not download anything to user's machine. So considering ClickOnce Deployment could solve your issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: So through clickonce...do you mean i have to create and publish a windows installer? is there any other way so that user don't have to do anything(like executing installer etc). instead application(with all the dlls' and folder structure) should get downloaded after clicking button on webpage.

Comment: you can use content disposition (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive) to download the files to user's machine, but still you will not be able to specify the location and also wont be able to execute the file, only user can select the location to download and execute it.